figure element with aspect ratio not working in safari
This code is working properly in chrome & firefox; not in safari.
https://jsfiddle.net/aurpa/t4z0beuL/
<style>
  figure {
    display: block;
    max-width: 10vw;
    max-height: 30vh;
    background: red;
    aspect-ratio: var(--aspect-ratio);

  }

  figure>img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain !important;
  }

</style>

<figure id="" style="--aspect-ratio: 2.3748810656518" class="img-container landscape" data-color="#272846" data-order="1" data-scrollama-index="0">
  <img data-lazyload="" alt="Grand Horizontal" data-color="#272846" data-imgheight="" data-src="https://catherineviollet.fr/media/pages/projets/les-chemins-d-eau/14155ef03e-1714326097/grand-horizontal-2022-acrylique-pigments-fraisage-sur-papier-124x300-1500x.jpg" loading="lazy" src="https://catherineviollet.fr/media/pages/projets/les-chemins-d-eau/14155ef03e-1714326097/grand-horizontal-2022-acrylique-pigments-fraisage-sur-papier-124x300-1500x.jpg">


</figure>

<figure id="" style="--aspect-ratio: 0.62680361946686;" class="img-container" data-color="#2F315A" data-order="2" data-scrollama-index="1">
  <img data-lazyload="" alt="Gulf Stream" data-color="#2F315A" data-imgheight="" data-src="https://catherineviollet.fr/media/pages/projets/les-chemins-d-eau/29fdecc0af-1714326097/gulf-stream-2021-acrylique-pigments-fraisage-sur-papier-210x130-1500x.jpg" src="https://catherineviollet.fr/media/pages/projets/les-chemins-d-eau/29fdecc0af-1714326097/gulf-stream-2021-acrylique-pigments-fraisage-sur-papier-210x130-1500x.jpg">

</figure>



aspect-ratio: var(--aspect-ratio) is not preserved in safari.
Behavior in firefox & chrome:
(figure is streched based on the max width and max-height and preserves the aspect ratio)

Behavior in safari:
figure is stretched but doesn't preserve the aspect ratio, also the image is out of the figure element)


Please put code into the question, not on an external site, and please ensure that you use images which we can see. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and test that the snippet works.

Please check that the code you have given is runnable by us. We can't see images on a local host for example. And make the code into a snippet (<> in the editor) and TRY it yourself.

yep, sorry didn't check for local files — should be fixed now :)

Afraid I cannot test as it isn't a snippet - please convert to a snippet (<>) [I am on IOS for Safari so need runnable code].
